# Wireless driver causes frequent system freezes

Tags: wireless

For the past one month I am facing random freezes on my Asus 1005px EEEpc. Here I have filed a [public bug report on launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/671443). There I was informed that it is a duplicate of an [already reported bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/671374). I was adviced not to shift to ubuntu 10.10 netbook edition in an answer to the question [I posted here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11205/generating-an-app-list-from-the-old-installation-to-run-it-on-the-new-installatio). By turning off the network services, wireless and also after some tests, I strongly believe that it is caused by the wireless driver. The wireless card is: Atheros AR2427. I have to install the drivers manually by executing this command:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-backports-modules-wireless-maverick-generic
```

There is no response on the bug report page. The issue has become a big pain. Many times I have lost very imprortant work because of that bug. Please suggest some solution. If there is no solution, atleast tell me how can I avoid system freezes.

Comment: If possible in the future avoid Atheros, I have a long story of issues with those wifi cards.

Comment: Yes you are right. I installed archlinux to find out if the issue was specific to ubuntu. When the wireless was not being used, archlinux performed very well. The moment I set up a ad-hoc network, same freeze occured on it too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately it looks like that card isn't supported yet, but you could try [these instructions](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1481983).

Comment: Thanks for the link. I compiled and installed a recent version of the driver. The system remained up for few hours without going into a freeze (which hasn't happened before).I will do few more tests. I hope it will work.

Comment: Yes it solved the issue. So the driver available from apt has bugs.