# SSHFS hangs during file copy

Tags: 11.04, wireless, ssh, atheros, sshfs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [System freeze caused by ath9k driver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38043/system-freeze-caused-by-ath9k-driver)

I use `sshfs` to handle transfers between servers, but have been running into problems since installing 11.04. I'm not sure if the problem at this point is in my wireless driver (Atheros 9285) or SSH/SSHFS. My wireless does work fine other than when transferring across SSHFS, but when I copy a large file across SSHFS, it copies several MBs, then hangs. I can actually get it to restart by disconnecting and reconnecting my wireless network through Network Manager. Several other things stop when it hangs as well, like the monitor panel applet.

The machine I'm copying to still runs 10.04.

I see no messages in the dmesg logs.I've seen a couple of references to problems in Natty for both the Atheros cards, and ssh/sshd. I've installed the wireless backports, but see no difference. Does anyone have any ideas about what the problem could be?