# How do I list the default installed packages?

Tags: system-installation, package-management

I am developing an offline installer for all versions of Ubuntu, and I need Ubuntu's default installed packages list. Is there a way to get this information from any server (web server)? Any script to fetch any Ubuntu version's default installed packages list.

I will give the Ubuntu version, and the script will fetch the packages list.

**Note: I need at least a server address. I can write a script for this.**

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Going off [a previous answer of mine](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11205/generating-an-app-list-from-the-old-installation-to-run-it-on-the-new-installatio), there are manifest files available that should list all the packages included on the CD.

The URLs of the files are fairly predictable but in constant flux (as new releases come out and old ones are killed off) so a good strategy is:

1. Go to http://releases.ubuntu.com/ (for currently supported versions) or http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ (for other versions,  server images, etc.)
2. Pick your spin
3. Pick `releases`
4. Pick a version (eg 14.04)
5. Pick `release` (if it has been released)
6. Find the applicable `.manifest` file.

Note that not all these packages *stay* installed. On the CD images, you'll also find a file called `/capsper/filesystem.manifest-remove` which is a list of things to remove after installation. I can't find an online copy of these files on their own.

Comment: Predictable perhaps, but broken.

Comment: @PaulDraper Not broken in so much as constantly changing. I've updated the answer with a DIY approach that should last the test of time.

Comment: There don't seem to be manifest files anymore..

Comment: @Seth For Ubuntu, the `.manifest` files are available for any supported releases at http://releases.ubuntu.com/ and other flavours continue to have the files at the cdimage server.

Comment: This answer used to point to releases.ubuntu.com but the practical problem is it only lists supported releases. I took the view that the question is more about the original install (which may now well be an unsupported release). I'll edit it back in.

Comment: ([here](https://gist.github.com/rubo77/1d368cc20cec4ede39e917a8a2b9e4fc) is this file `/capsper/filesystem.manifest-remove` from Ubuntu 17.10)

Comment: Why is some of the software removed? Would be good to say it on answer.

Comment: To get just the package list use `wget http://releases.ubuntu.com/$RELEASE/ubuntu-$VERSION-desktop-amd64.manifest -q -O - | cut -f 1 | xargs`