# Default package list

Tags: package-management

Is it possible to find a place where the default package in Ubuntu releases are?
By default, I mean all the packages installed when you install Ubuntu.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I list the default installed packages?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48886/how-do-i-list-the-default-installed-packages)

Answer (score 0):

The file is in `/etc/apt/sources.list`  You can read it with:  `gedit /etc/apt/sources.list`

You can back it up before making changes with

`cp /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.original`