# How do I know what programming languages are pre-installed in Ubuntu?

Tags: python, programming, ruby, c, preinstallation

How do I know what programming languages (I mean their compilers and interpreters) are already pre-installed in Ubuntu? For example, I see that Python is here. If I type `python` command in the terminal, it turns out that I have python version 2.7.12. But what about other popular programming and scripting languages like Ruby, Perl, C, Lua, awk, Java, PHP, etc. etc. Should I try to launch them in the terminal or try something like `language --version` one by one, or is there a better way to know this?

Comment: You cannot "install" a language on any system .. there are interpreters and compilers you install and since they are sometimes similar sometimes really different I don't think there is a simple way to check for all of them rather than checking one by one

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An [article](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PowerUsersProgramming) in Ubuntu's own help pages points out five (perl, python, ruby, awk, and sed) are installed by default.

Comment: Ruby? Note that the community wiki used to be editable by anyone, so it's not authoritative.

Answer (score 4):

As of latest LTS release , 16.04, Ubuntu comes with Perl 5, GNU awk (used to be mawk), Python 2 and 3 by default. Not entirely sure about C compiler. You may need `build-essential` package installed

For everything else, use `apt-cache policy **package-name**` to see if it is installed. You can also view the release manifest files as described in this answer:https://askubuntu.com/a/48894/295286

Comment: There are also Bash and dash.

Comment: @ChaiT.Rex Well, they're shells technically, both conforming to standard Shell Command Language specifications, but `bash` having more advanced syntax. So technically they're not "programming languages" as in C or Python sense, but yes good mention of the two.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a small bash script. Its very basic but its something

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

languages="php python go perl mysql c c++ java"
binaries="ls /usr/bin"

for i in $languages ; do
    for j in $($binaries); do
        if [[ $i == $j ]]; then
            echo $i
        fi
    done
done
```

Answer (score 1):

type `whereis [program]`. if nothing shows up then it is not installed. A rather silly way,but still usable.