# Why does Ubuntu 17.10 not look like it after upgrade from 16.04

Tags: apt, unity, gnome, upgrade

I have upgraded to Ubuntu 17.10 from 16.04.

Since everything has changed with the that release regarding the desktop manager, I could image there being *some* trouble.
But it seems, Ubuntu is back to 'a lot of trouble during upgrading' again.

I have the following problems:

- My closing buttons are not on the right side
- I do not have a dock visible on the left hand side.
- I have no dock settings, which is kind of logical, because I have no dock
- I have no transparency
- I have still the old ubuntu settings dialog (unity7)

What I have tried

- Installing gdm3 by hand (`sudp apt install ubuntu-session gdm3`), which changed the login screen, but leaves the desktop etc. broken as described
- I have purged unity8, which somehow brought `ubuntu-system-settings` over me, which I have also  purged
- Changing the used manager on the login screen, which works as far as it changes the desktop from unity8 to gnome or gnome on wayland.

Can I somehow trigger the repair of the Ubuntu installation? I figure it is broken somehow? Or did it just ignore some packages, because there were packages installed for that purpose already?

Comment: Did you upgrade 16.04 -> 16.10 -> 17.04 -> 17.10 ? Or did you skip releases ? Does 17.10 work from a live USB ?

Comment: Straight from LTS to 17.10. haven't tried live usb. Why?

Comment: Are you sure you're not using gnome-shell, which is the default in 17.10?

Comment: From what I've seen from the freshly installed Ubuntu 17.10s on YouTube, mine is different. How may I check if I use the correct one?

Comment: Boot a live 17.10 usb and see, lol. With all those upgrades and significant changes you may be best off with a fresh install. You can try deleting all you gnome and unity settings in $HOME and log out and back in

Comment: @user535733 My system is 17.10 not 17.04 after the upgrade ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is simple: I had Ubuntu 17.04 installed, which was Ubuntu's safest update way apparently.

Ubuntu does not seem to upgrade from 16.04 directly to the newest release.

It works all fine now after another upgrade to from 17.04 to 17.10.

If you are nevertheless stuck in a situation where your upgrade did not go as planned, I suggest you have look at the Ubuntu manifest file for your version of Ubuntu. It contains all the packages that SHOULD be installed with a fresh installation and might help you to figure out which ones are missing for you or which ones you could trigger a reconfigure for.
You can find a good answer for that here: [How do I list the default installed packages?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48886/how-do-i-list-the-default-installed-packages)

Comment: So, are you saying that you really went from 16.04 to 17.04, instead of to 17.10? Then another Software Update should be able to bring you from 17.04 to 17.10, yes?

Comment: @heynnema Yep. Updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

It may be that your login is still set to Unity.

At the login screen, click on your username, then click the small cog wheel icon, and select either `Gnome`, or `Gnome on xorg`, or `Gnome on wayland`. Then proceed to enter your password to log in.

You'll know that you've reached the new software because the calendar/clock/notification area will appear in the center of the top panel.

To make the dock appear, review your installed gnome extensions at https://extensions.gnome.org/local/ and enable the built-in `Ubuntu Dock` extension. The `Ubuntu Dock` is a paired-down version of `Dash to Dock`, and if you prefer more customization options then disable the built-in `Ubuntu Dock` and install/configure `Dash to Dock` which is found at:

https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/307/dash-to-dock/

**Update:**

Recommend (re)installing 17.10 to cure the various problems.

Comment: There may be another choice, Ubuntu on Xorg, which seems to be Gnome with the dock set up for you.

Comment: I figured that the dock was an extension, but could not install it via apt, because it was not found. I do not have the option "Gnome on Xorg" though. But I have the clock centered as you say, when I chose a "gnome option"

Comment: What about the missing transparency and the old settings menu though?

Comment: @func0der The `Ubuntu Dock` and the `Dash to Dock` are not installed using apt. Either use the https://extensions.gnome.org/local/ or use the Gnome Tweak Tool. The second link that I gave will take you directly to the `Dash to Dock` install page.

Comment: It says "You don't have any extensions installed." on the page. I can not find the `Ubuntu Dock` extension in the catalog.

Comment: @func0der then there's something really wrong with your installation and you need to reinstall.

Comment: @heynnema No, i refuse to believe that. The ubuntu dock has to be a an apt package then. This is windows style of doing things, just 'reinstalling'. Ubuntu and others should be capable of managing this stuff via the packages.

Comment: @func0der well, you upgraded, and didn't follow the recommended path of performing all of the intermediate upgrades, and have multiple problems, including none of the standard gnome extensions showing as installed. Ubuntu Dock is not an apt package. Reinstall is VERY indicated. Believe what you will.

Comment: @heynnema Where is the page that recommends me to upgrade to 17.04 before going to 17.10? If that is recommended, why didn't Ubuntu itself upgrad to the intermediate releases first?

Comment: http://releases.ubuntu.com/17.10/ubuntu-17.10-desktop-amd64.manifest <- it is a package

Comment: @func0der  `gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock` can be installed by itself, but it won't fix your other problems. It also doesn't have all of the features as `Dash to Dock` that I recommended 8 hours ago. With all of the arguments, you could have already fixed the problem(s) with a reinstall that I recommended 1/2 hour ago.

Comment: I wanted the stock Ubuntu stuff. I wanted help to fix an installation, I did not want to reinstall the whole system.

Comment: This was the correct answer for me. I've upgraded from 16.04 to 18.04 and been looking for a way to change to the new default look and feel (I prefer it to unity anyway).

Answer (score 0):

Likely there's an issue somewhere where it isn't flipping over to the new software defaults. It may be from skipping significant releases, it really could be a number of things.

If you can't flip everything over by just installing some new packages or resetting some defaults or switching to the new shell when starting up (from the login screen)... it may just be best to do a fresh install.

Sometimes fresh installs are just better that way, even though it can be annoying to have to set it all up.

Comment: That is not a satisfying answer to me. I do not want to install fresh. There has to be a way to make this work without going fresh. Instead, please list 'a number of things'.