# Getting full Ubuntu after a basic installation

Tags: gnome, package-management, configuration

I installed Ubuntu 18.04 some time ago on a computer and I don't remember exactly what I chose, but it must have been something like a basic/minimal installation, because some packages are missing (I had to install libreoffice-gnome for example). I was wondering if it's possible to install all the other packages I'm missing but that are available in the "full" configuration without completely reinstalling Ubuntu?

Comment: You can install missing packages with `sudo apt update` and then `sudo apt install packagename1 packagename2` and so on.  Do you know what packages you want that you don't have?  If you installed the minimal system and you want all of the default packages, the easiest and fastest way is probably to just start over and reinstall your whole system, rather than picking through the [list of already installed packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17823/how-to-list-all-installed-packages).  But before you do that, what is the end goal? Right now you can just install what you need..

Comment: Thanks for your answer! That's the problem: I don't know which packages precisely to install. The end goal is simply to have a nicer looking/smoother interface (LibreOffice for example looks Windows 98-esque without libreoffice-gnome), so nothing serious.

Comment: the installation media that you originally used should have [manifest files](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48886/how-do-i-list-the-default-installed-packages) available that list all of the included packages included on the .ISO.  The tricky part would be comparing the two lists, while also keeping in mind that your current list will already have many different packages due to updates and their dependencies plus any user-installed software. Both lists will also contain thousands of packages.  Best to just look for the package that contains the thing you want.

Comment: Thank you! I don't have this computer with me right now, but I think yours is the best answer I can get!